# Bootstrap Header Background Mobile Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, responsive-design, padding

I have a the following:

```
<header class="container-fluid" id="header">...</header>
```

This has a background image applied to it and spans the full width of the screen on Desktop view. However when you resize the window to a mobile device size there is extra white padding around the sides which means the background isnt covering the full screen and is infact the same with as the content inside the

What would be the best way to acheve this? Note. The background is only for the header section of the page not the whole page.

Desktop View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKsxa.jpg

Mobile View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GArgd.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At viewpoints 767px and less, Bootstrap adds 20px padding to the left and the right of the body, ie

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
body {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
}
```

So if you want the header background to extend full width, you need to override this.

Something like the following should do the trick.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
#header {
padding-right: -20px;
padding-left: -20px;
}
}
```

Good luck!